# iterate using curl on a custom list

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, curl

I need to run a curl delete command on a list which is coming in from a rest API.

```
workspace_allocations = requests.get('https://api.onelink.com/api/v1/workspace_allocations', headers=headers, params=params)
text2 = workspace_allocations.text
data2 = json.loads(text2)

#convert to a list for iterating

workspace_allocations1 = []
for ids in data2['results']:
    workspace_allocations1.append(ids['id'])
print(workspace_allocations1)
#Fetch the delete curl to run through the array

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ********-*******-*************',
}
for fn in workspace_allocations1:
    response = requests.delete('https://api.onelink.com/api/v1/workspace_allocations/fn', headers=headers)
print(response)

<Response [404]>
```

Output of the first print --> workspace_allocations1

```
['123697406', '123957117', '123957491', '123983488', '124074207', '124203018', '124229335', '124230125', '124246767', '124272164', '124272180', '124380726', '124397894', '124397895', '124397911', '124397912', '124397915', '124397923']
```

Is it possible to iterate over this array using curl???

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use f-strings to insert `fn` into the url string

```
for fn in workspace_allocations1:
  response = requests.delete(f'https://api.mavenlink.com/api/v1/workspace_allocations/{fn}', headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you, Dont know how i missed the basic ;-(. Time to unlearn a few things